# Angular 5 Model with child models. Multiple HTTP requests

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have this model structure

```
export class Car {
    id: number;
    exterior: Exterior;
    engine: Engine;
}

export class Exterior {
    color: string;
    doors: number;
}

export class Engine {
    model: string;
    horsePower: number;
}
```

Exterior and Engine have their own services called, ExteriorService and EngineService like so:

```
@Injectable()
export class ExteriorService {
    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient
    ) { }

    public getExterior(carId: number): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(`${url}`)
            .map(response => response);
    }
}
```

Which are both added in the app.module.ts

Now I want to be able to call one method from another component `getCar(carId: number)`, which will return a Car object for me, fully filled in (the children included). Then after it is fully filled in, I want to console.log it to be able to see all the data, children included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a chain
Subscribe

```
this.http.get("/api/car/1").subscribe(car => {
  this.http.get("/api/exterior/1").subscribe(exterior => {
    car.exterior = exterior;
    this.http.get("/api/engine/1").subscribe(engine => {
      car.engine = engine;
      this.car = car;
    });
  });
});
```

Method 2 MergeMap

```
this.car = this.http.get('/api/car/1')
.pipe(mergeMap(exterior => this.http.get("/api/exterior/1"))
.pipe(mergeMap(engine => this.http.get("/api/engine/1")));
```

Method 3 ForkJoin

```
let car = this.http.get('/api/car/1');
let exterior = this.http.get('/api/exterior/1');
let engine = this.http.get('/api/engine/1');

forkJoin([car, exterior, engine]).subscribe(data => {    
    data[0].exterior = data[1]
    data[0].engine = data[2];
    this.car = data[0];
  });
```

Comment: subscription chaining should be done with correct teardown logic to allow e.g. cancellation of requests

Answer (score 1):

you can use the RxJS forkJoin operator to join the results of the different asynchronous http calls, e.g.

```
getCar(carId: number) {
  return 
    forkJoin(
      this.http.get("/api/car/1"),
      this.http.get("/api/exterior/1"),
      this.http.get("/api/engine/1")
    ).pipe(map(parts => {
      const car = parts[0];
      car.exterior = parts[1];
      car.engine = parts[2];
    }));
}
```

That way, the requests run in parallel and can also be cancelled.

See https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html